# How can I set a reminder for every third item in a List in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a list which adds up item from another list through database in Android. But I need to set up a reminder for every third item, that is 3, 6, 9 , 12, etc. When I do like this

```
if( types.size() == 3 && types.size() == 6 && types.size() ==9)
```

my appliction closes unexpectedly. Below is my code. Its working when I only have one number, but I need it for all the third odd numbers. Any tips would be really valuable for me, Thank you

```
private List<AlcoholTypes> types = new ArrayList<AlcoholTypes>();
types = Database.getDataList(this);
if(types.size() == 3 ){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Water Reminder");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Drink one glass of water !")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Okay",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if( types.size() == 3 && types.size() == 6 && types.size() ==9)
```

to this:

```
if(types.size() % 3 == 0)
```

This makes use of modulo, which checks divisability and returns 0 if it is divisable by that number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Please mark it as the answer and upvote it if you can, that will help future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it I guess:

```
   if( types.size() % 3 == 0) {
         // do something special
    } else {
         // do something normal
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just check it size is divisible /3 or not that is enough